# Convention for checking the existence of a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the accepted way of checking a model's existence in a Django app?

I've seen this method used:

```
def profile_exists(user):
        try:
                UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)
                return True
        except:
                return False
```

Is there a built-in function suited for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bare `except`s should not be used. Instead the model's `DoesNotExist` inner exception or `django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist` [should be caught](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id5).

Beyond that, either this or using `len(SomeModel.objects.filter(...))` are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

As an additional note, you could make a general purpose function out of it with:

```
def object_exists(model, **kwargs):
       try:
             model.objects.get(**kwargs)
             return True
       except model.DoesNotExist:
             return False
```

And then simply call:

```
profile_exists = object_exists(UserProfile, user=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is suitable until the naked `except`.  You always get more than you bargain for with those!

As mentioned by [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams), one should make use of the built in `DoesNotExist` exception for the model:

```
def profile_exists(user):
        try:
                UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)
                return True
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                return False
```

Presto!

Answer (score 0):

There's always `get_object_or_404`, which as its name implies, either returns the object or raises an HttpNotFound error:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
instance = get_object_or_404(SomeModel, filter_args=whatever)
```